# Image doesn't refresh after coordinate update

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a `UIImage` (happyFace) that I'm moving around the screen when the user taps it. I also have a counter (tapLabel) that updates each time the image is tapped.
When I comment-out the update of the `tapLabel.text` the image moves on the screen.
When I do update the `tapLabel.text`, the image stays where it is, but its X and Y coordinates are updated. I'm using AutoLayout but have no constraints on the `UIImage`. Strange...

```
    // Assign the image's new position and update counter label
    happyFace.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(newX)
    happyFace.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(newY)

    tapLabel.text = String(tapCount)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had AutoLayout on so it would always reposition the image to the original position. I needed to update the constraints which allowed AutoLayout to do it's thing. My image then was able to move around the screen.
I got a new position for my image (newX, newY) and set those as my new constraints.

```
// Set up outlets from the image's constraints in the Storyboard
@IBOutlet weak var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


    // Set a new Leading (X) and Top (Y) constraints for the image
    let newLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: happyFace, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: newX)
    let newTopConstraint     = NSLayoutConstraint(item: happyFace, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: newY)

    // Remove the old image constraints and set the new ones (ie move the image)
    self.view.removeConstraint(leadingConstraint)
    self.view.removeConstraint(topConstraint)
    self.view.addConstraint(newLeadingConstraint)
    self.view.addConstraint(newTopConstraint)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()                 // Force the layout before drawing
    leadingConstraint = newLeadingConstraint
    topConstraint = newTopConstraint
```